# Add conditional column to Pandas Data Frame using else if logic - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

need some help...

Below is my **Data Frame**:

```
+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+
| Planned_Date | Planned_Date_2 | Complete_Date | Complete_Date_2 | Alias_Date |
+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+
| 01/01/1800   |                | 03/09/2020    |                 | 03/09/2020 |
| 01/01/1800   | 20/09/2020     |               |                 | 20/09/2020 |
|              |                |               | 28/09/2020      | 28/09/2020 |
| 04/10/2020   |                |               |                 | 04/10/2020 |
+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to **create a new column** (**Alias_Date**) using conditional logic against a few date columns:

The logic is as follows:

```
if Planned_Date = 01/01/1800
  and Planned_Date_2 = null
    then Complete_Date

else if Planned_Date  = 01/01/1800
  and Planned_Date_2  <> null
    then Planned_Date_2 

else if Planned_Date = null
    then Complete_Date_2

else Planned_Date
```

How can I efficiently do this using python/pandas/numpy or any other recommended means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forward filling missing values and select last column by position with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['Alias_Date'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

If possible some another columns in DataFrame select them by list:

```
cols = ['Planned_Date', 'Planned_Date_2', 'Complete_Date', 'Complete_Date_2']


df['Alias_Date'] = df[cols].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Or first 4 columns:

```
df['Alias_Date'] = df.iloc[:, :4].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Or columns with `Date`:

```
df['Alias_Date'] = df.filter(like='Date').ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

EDIT:

Solution with selecting columns in [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
cols = ['Planned_Date', 'Planned_Date_2', 'Complete_Date', 'Complete_Date_2']

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

m1 = df['Planned_Date'].eq('1800-01-01')
m2 = df['Planned_Date_2'].isna()
m3 = df['Planned_Date'].isna()

df['Alias_Date'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2, m3], 
                             [df['Complete_Date'], 
                              df['Planned_Date_2'], 
                              df['Complete_Date_2']], default=df['Planned_Date'])
print (df)
  Planned_Date Planned_Date_2 Complete_Date Complete_Date_2 Alias_Date
0   1800-01-01            NaT    2020-09-03             NaT 2020-09-03
1   1800-01-01     2020-09-20           NaT             NaT 2020-09-20
2          NaT            NaT           NaT      2020-09-28 2020-09-28
3   2020-10-04            NaT           NaT             NaT 2020-10-04
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thank you for your prompt response. This is quite a clever solution, however, the data is coming from a database in which there are hundreds of other columns, moreover, the columns are not in this order. Additionally, new columns are added and others are taken away. So, although this would work in the context provided, it's not dynamic enough for the current setup. Apologies for not providing this information in the question. Sorry, just to add, the columns are not always null as shown in the example dataset, that was just a simple sample to show what I'm trying to achieve.